# Regex for euro sign (€)

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract currencies with € sign in the text and my text is eg:

```
"€0.74 million developer fund  of €2 billion carbon emission"
```

my regex is:

```
"(\u20AC)[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\s(m|b)illion+"
```

when I run regex on the text i am getting below output:

```
[[1]]
character(0)
```

can anyone tell what is wrong with regex and why I am not able to extract € sign even after putting `(\u20AC)` for that.

Comment: Please share your code and also please let know what output you expect.

Comment: my code is "(\u20AC)[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\s(m|b)illion+" and i expect [1] "€0.74 million" "€2 billion"

Comment: It is not a code, it is a regex. Regex is used inside code. Please share the code.

Comment: str_extract_all(coll(txt,ignore_case = TRUE),  "(\u20AC)[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\s(m|b)illion+") is my code where txt = "€0.74 million developer fund  of €2 billion carbon emission"

Comment: Try just `str_extract_all(txt, "(?i)€[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?\\s*[mb]illion")`

Answer (score 3):

Using stringr. In your regex, `\s` should be `\\s` . Below uses

`\\d` for digits (just simpler than [0-9]

`(.\\d+)?` for optional decimal points - everything in parentheses before ?

```
s <- "€0.74 million developer fund of €2 billion carbon emission" 
r <-  "(\u20AC)\\d+(.\\d+)?\\s(m|b)illion+"
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(s,r)

# [1] "€0.74 million" "€2 billion"
```

Comment: epi99 when i follow your answer i am getting below                                        [[1]]
character(0)

Comment: @NaveenGoud, its hard to know what;s different. i suggest keep simplifying the regex to see where the problem lies. One guess may be encoding - so try the regex without the encoding for euro symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a different code...  Like

```
((\x80)[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\s(m|b)illion).*
```

This will capture the euro in a proper way

(I used gsub btw:

```
z = "€0.74 million developer fund  of €2 billion carbon emission"
gsub("((\x80)[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\s(m|b)illion).*","\\1",z)
```

However, this only catches the first one now... but I think that is easily solvable)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not match the strings because your pattern, `(€)[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\s(m|b)illion+`, namely the `[0-9]+.[0-9]+` part, requires at least 2 digits that should be "split" with any 1 char. It means, you may match `1t6 million`, or `1.6 billionnnn` (several `n`s are matched because of quantified `n`, `n+`).

You do not get any matches because you werote `€` as `\u20AC`, or you would get 1 match, `0.74 million`:

```
> p = "(€)[0-9]+.[0-9]+\\s(m|b)illion+"
> str_extract_all(txt, p)
[[1]]
[1] "\u00800.74 million"
```

To solve the issue, you may use a base R `regmatches` with `gregexpr`:

```
> txt <- "€0.74 million developer fund  of €2 billion carbon emission"
> res <- regmatches(txt, gregexpr("€[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?\\s*[mb]illion", txt, ignore.case=TRUE))
> lapply(res, cat, "\n")
€0.74 million €2 billion 
[[1]]
NULL
```

Note I used `cat` to display the Unicode string results as these are actual extracted values.

**Pattern details**

- `€`  - a euro sign
- `[0-9]+`  - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\\.[0-9]+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of a `.` and then 1 or more digits
- `\\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[mb]` - `m` or `b`
- `illion` - a literal substring.